# Book suggestion about deploying real deep learning models in real world

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, books, robotics, real-time

Can you suggest books about deploying machine learning algorithms on robots, especially on real time stream? I don't know how to deal with latency and other challenges that real time inference/stream presents.